# Rename folders/directories in one go based on metadata with R

Tags: r, directory, metadata, rename

I have a question that concerns renaming folders based on information in a metadataframe. Underneath you will find my directory structure and an example of the .information of the metadata. This means that folders with the name S1 will be named V_3_4 etc. Folders S1,S2, S3 etc. can be found in both D0 and D1 folders.

Metadataframe:

| date | Sample_name | S_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021_05_20 | V_3_4 | S1 |
| 2021_05_20 | V_9_4 | S2 |
| 2021_05_20 | H_13_5 | S3 |

Directory structure:

```
main Directory
        |
        |___ 2021_metadata.txt
        |___ Experiment
                ├── D0
                   ├── Weather
                           |__ S1
                           |__ S2
                           
                │  └── Temperature
                           |__ S1
                           |__ S2
                └── D1
                   ├── Weather
                           |__ S1
                           |__ S2
                           |__ S3
                   └── Temperature
```

I tried to do this with this code:

```
name_file <- "./20210325_metadata_r_test_1.txt"

Metadataframe <- read.delim(name_file)


dirs <- list.dirs(path = path, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

if(any(dirs %in% Metadataframe$S_number)){
    for(dir in dirs[which(dirs %in% Metadataframe$S_number)]){
        shell(paste("move", dir, Metadataframe$Sample_name[which(Metadataframe$S_number == dir)]))
    }
}
```

This code works when I want to do it separately by putting in list.dirs the path of a specific folder such as ~/main directory/experiment/D0/Weather. However, I want to rename all the folders in one go (so also in D0/temperature, D1/Weather and D1/temperature). I tried to do the list.dirs() from the main directory to get all directories, but then the code is not doing anything. It does not rename the folders. What am I doing wrong and is there a way to fix this?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

I guess you simply need another for loop. See if this helps

```
paths <- paste0("~/main directory/experiment/", c("D0/temperature", "D1/Weather", "D1/temperature"))

invisible(lapply(paths, function(path){
  dirs <- list.dirs(path = path, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
  
  if(any(dirs %in% Metadataframe$S_number)){
    for(dir in dirs[which(dirs %in% Metadataframe$S_number)]){
      shell(paste("move", dir, Metadataframe$Sample_name[which(Metadataframe$S_number == dir)]))
    }
  }
  return(NULL)
}))
```